# Обращение к подстолбцу `Dataframe` `Python`

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, pandas, dataframe

Мне необходимо построить график зависимости среднего значения одного столбца из сгруппированной таблицы, от другого. С помощью:

```py
reshelp = df.groupby("ProfileName").agg({'Score': ["std","count"], 'HelpfulnessNumerator': ["mean"]}).reset_index()
```

Я создал следующую таблицу:

```
                         ProfileName     Score       HelpfulnessNumerator
                                           std       count                 mean
0                                       2.828427     2                  1.0
1                                    0.000000     2                  0.0
2                                   NaN        1                  1.0
3                      :Jury Duty:     1.414214     4                  3.0
4  ! MR. KNOW IT ALL  ;-b "DR SHOCK"     1.763834     10                  1.4
```

Теперь мне необходимо построить график зависимости `HelpfulnessNumerator.mean` от `Score.count`. 
Пробовал построить по аналогии с обычным построением:

```py
reshelp.plot.scatter(x="Score.count", y="HelpfulnessNumerator.mean",title='Helpfulness of expert review depended by number of reviews')
```

Но на данную запись выдает ошибку, не читает `Score.count`.
Как обращаться к таким подстолбцам корректно?

Comment: вы можете привести в вопросе вывод `reshelp.to_dict("records")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело скорее в `Score.count`, scatter не распознает такой синтаксис.
Попробуйте так

```
import seaborn as sns  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

sns.scatterplot(x=reshelp['Score', 'count'], y=reshelp['HelpfulnessNumerator', 'mean'])  
plt.title('Helpfulness of expert review depended by number of reviews')
```